# Can we get/access the photo related settings from built in settings app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings

I found current version,model and other things to get using UIDevice & NSLocale but I want to get the information about settings->photos

How can i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, there is no API for that.

Comment: We can't get even? I don't want to modify I just want to check. We have location,country,version & all other details that is to be get & access

Comment: Generally, you can't access other apps' preferences.

Answer (score 1):

No public API known for that. You simply can't do that without your app being rejected.